# Converting table with Varchar columns to custom JSON in Snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that has the following data

| START_DATE | NAME | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/18/2022 | JOHN | 10 |
| 01/19/2022 | ADAM | 20 |

I am trying to convert this to JSON in a custom format like below -

```
{
 "labels":{
           "name":"JOHN",
           "id":[10]
          }
 "values":{
           "startDate":"01/18/2022"
          }
}
```

PARSE_JSON way of

```
SELECT parse_json('{"values": {startDate: A.STARTDATE}}')
FROM TABLE_A A;
```

resulted in error

```
Error parsing JSON: unknown keyword "A", pos 25
```

OBJECT_CONSTRUCT results in converting column name as key and column value as value.

Please advise how to have custom field names in JSON conversion in Snowflake.

Comment: can you give a try with below query:Select
    OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('ID',id::string,'NAME',name) as labels,
    OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
        'start_date',
        START_DATE::string) as aa,
        object_insert(object_construct('labels', labels), 'a', aa)
        from
            Test1;

Comment: Thank you, Anand ! What do object_insert and aa mean here?

Comment: Also, ID needs to be an array not string

Comment: Can you mark if answer is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renamed objects names as per data given   and changed Id to array:

```
create table test1 values(START_DATE date, NAME string,ID number);
insert into test1(START_DATE, NAME,ID ) values('01/18/2022','JOHN', 10);
insert into test1(START_DATE, NAME,ID ) values('01/19/2022','ADAM', 20);
    Select
        OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('ID',id::array,'NAME',name) as label_obj,
        OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
            'start_date',
            START_DATE::string) as start_dt_obj,
            object_insert(object_construct('labels', label_obj), 'values', start_dt_obj) as final_json
            from
                Test1;
```

Comment: Thank you ! This worked perfectly !